# Is it possible to redirect requests and return responses with TIdHTTP (client) in TIdHTTPServer onCommandGet event?

Tags: delphi, httpclient, indy, httpserver

I'm wondering if I can have onCommandGet event where I can redirect the client request to another host/port, get the information I need with TIdHTTP (client) and send it back to the client via AResponseInfo ?

It shoold look like this :

```
procedure HTTPServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
client : TIdHTTP;
begin
  client := TIdHTTP.Create();
  try
    client.Request := ARequestInfo; // or somehow put the ARequestInfo in the client
    ... // in here I don't know how to make the GET, POST, HEAD or other 
    ... // (if possible) request to 'some_host:some_port'
    AResponseInfo := client.Response; // or somehow put the client Response in AResponseInfo
  finally
    FreeAndNil(client);
  end;


end;
```

Comment: Formally you should return `AResponseInfo.Redirect('redir_host:port');` and let the client handle the redirection by itself. But I feel that the reason for your question might be that you want to do some stuff on a server "hidden" to the client, where the formal redirection is not an option. Just to let you know...

Comment: @TLama Yes - you're right - and one of the "hidden" things is the actual host:port from where I will collect the information that the client needs and send it back to him via AResponseInfo - making him think he got it from the url he just typed

Answer (score 2):

There is no native solution to do what you are asking for.  You will have to implement it manually.  Copy the relevant values from `ARequestInfo` properties into `TIdHTTP.Request` as needed, then call `TIdHTTP.Get()`, `TIdHTTP.Post()`, etc as needed, and then copy the relevant values from `TIdHTTP.Response` into `AResponseInfo` as needed.

Comment: That's pretty much what I want to do - I just don't know which ARequestInfo and AResponseInfo properties I need to use/set in order to make things work as If there wasn't any TIdHTTP in the middle ?